# How to save function variable to file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, workspace

I want to make a script that saves multiple base variables from the "base name". My attempt looks like this :

```
function [outargs] = save_with_basename(b)

basePath = 'C:\path\';

Var1 = evalin('base', [b '_1']);
Var2 = evalin('base', [b '_2']); % .. etc

for i=1:N
    save([basePath b '_' int2str(i) '.mat'], ['Var' int2str(i)]);
end

end
```

This saves the files but the variable saved in the file is called `Var1` (see the pic.), but I want it to be called 'Foo_1' if the function was called with :

```
save_with_basename('Foo');
```

I think the second argument to `save` works with the function variable, so it looks like I have to change its name dynamically (which is probably not possible?) , so I wonder if there is a way I can do it.

**Here is the problem :** 
[image]

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of everything that is holy, please do not do this.

If you really have to, please *please* **please** do not do this.

If you really really *really* <strike>have to</strike> want to, you indeed need to use dynamic variables (but that doesn't make much of a difference now, does it?):

```
for i=1:N %what's N again?
   evalin('base',['Var' num2str(i) '=' b '_' num2str(i)]);
   evalin('base',['save([''' basePath b '_' num2str(i) '.mat''], [''Var' num2str(i) '''])']);
end
```

This will essentially perform

```
Var1 = "b"_1; %with whatever b is
Var2 = "b"_2;
...
save(['C:\path\b_1.mat'],['Var1']); %with whatever b is
save(['C:\path\b_2.mat'],['Var2']);
```

in your base workspace, so it will generate the `Var*` variables there. Small price to pay for selling your soul to the devil. Note that I may have missed the escaping of the single quotes in the second `evalin`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andras. Yes this is probably not the best way to do what I'm doing. But I remember I wanted to do this before, too. Just wondered if there is a simple solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @halilpazarlama I would suggest avoiding the generation of `b_1,b_2,...` in the first place: use cells, structs or arrays depending on your data. Then you can pass the whole data set to your function for export. Hint: you can access `varname.fieldname` like this: `fieldstr='fieldname'; varname.(fieldstr)`.

Comment: Keeping them as fields or cell contents would probably be better, yes. But in my case there are few (N=3) but each one contains big matrices. And I'm working on a PC with a limited memory, (also have to share them with Dropbox) So I want to save them inside separate files, in case I want to use only one of them.

Comment: @halilpazarlama, all I'm saying is that instead of `b1,b2,b3`, have `b{1},b{2},b{3}`; then you can pass `b`, the cell, to your exporting function, which can then do `Var1=b{1}; Var2=b{2}; Var3=b{3}; save(...,Var1);` and so on. Worst case scenario: you need a single `eval` for the generation of the var name `Var1`. Or you could use structs, like `b.f1, b.f2, b.f3`, after which `for i=1:N, Var.(['f' num2str(i)])=b.(['f' num2str(i)]); end`, and --- tadaa --- no more `eval`s;)

Comment: I think I understand now. Ok I will try like this. Thanks :)

Comment: @halilpazarlama No problem:) If you're stuck, go ahead and ask a new question. There will be many people (including me) who will go a long way to prevent you from using dynamic variables, or any kind of `eval` for that matter.

Comment: Thanks Andras. I actually solved my problem by letting Var1 to be the variable name, so changed the code that reads these files.

Comment: @halilpazarlama, ah, sorry, I forgot along the way that you wanted to have dynamic variables in the first place. Anyway, I'm happy to hear that you got around that;)